# TCPDF ERROR: pagination issue

Tags: pagination, tcpdf

When I try to insert content more than 10000 words, PDF is not generating, it is not able to create 2 page so that content display properly:

```
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->writeHTML(  $f_html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('workorder1.pdf', 'I');
```

http://propertyconditionreporter.com/new%20pdf/generate_PDF.php?id=109

Comment: The error says there is an image missing.  It wont generate with missing images.  You can reference the image as an http:// call..

Comment: But I am not calling any image, I am just adding content without image. as content increased more than one page, it throw this error

Comment: This has been fixed, issue was coming as there was space in new pdf folder. Please make sure there should not be space in folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed, issue was coming as there was space in new pdf folder. Please make sure there should not be space in folders